# Doxygen @ref with custom text for link

Tags: syntax, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

How would I go about naming a Doxygen `@ref` tag?

I have tried the following:

```
See @ref hello_world hello for more information
```

Which outputs this:

```
See hello_world hello for more information
```

Where `hello_world` is linked to `hello_world`. I am looking for this output:

```
See hello for more information
```

Where `hello` is linked to `hello_world`. The documentation for Doxygen only contains information about the LaTeX form of `@ref` (`\ref`), and I do not know how to apply that to the JavaDoc style `@ref`.

How would I go about changing the "text" value of the link?

Comment: From the documentation: nref <name> [”(text)”], so it looks like you missed the quotes: See @ref hello_world "hello for more information".

Comment: @albert That's it! `@ref hello_world "hello"` works. It'd be great if you could post that as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the documentation the syntax is: `\ref <name> ["(text)"]`

Were the `[...]` signs mean optional.

Hence it looks like you missed the quotes: `See @ref hello_world "hello for more information"`.